# I am getting this exception "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed". What am I doing wrong?

Tags: sql, exception, resultset

I am getting this exception

> "Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed"

I am not sure it is because I am using two result sets.

```
public static void updateLength() {
        try {
            Connection db_connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/omdb", "root", "");

            Statement statement_object = db_connection.createStatement();

            String sql_query_str = "SELECT * FROM movies ";
            String sql_query_str2 = "SELECT * FROM movie_numbers ";

            ResultSet result_set = statement_object.executeQuery(sql_query_str);
            ResultSet result_set2 = statement_object.executeQuery(sql_query_str2);

            while (result_set.next()) {
                String native_name = result_set.getString("native_name");
                int nativeName_length = API.getLength(native_name);
                int id = result_set.getInt("movie_id");
                int id2 = result_set2.getInt("movie_id");
                
                String sql = "insert into movie_numbers " + " (length)" + " values (?)";

                PreparedStatement preparedStmt = db_connection.prepareStatement(sql);
                
                if(id2!=id) {
                    //preparedStmt.setInt(1, id);
                    preparedStmt.setInt(1, nativeName_length);
                }
                else if (id2==id) {
                    preparedStmt.setInt(2, nativeName_length);

                }
                
                
                preparedStmt.execute();
                
                
                
            }
            
            
            
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Got an exception!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

Comment: One thing, you call result_set.next() before doing the getString, but you don't call result_set2.next() anywhere.

Comment: Apparently, it started working when I create a different statement object for results set 2.